# Loading Excel file in C# - Empty columns and rows are automatically trimmed

Tags: c#, excel

I've a problem loading Excel files from C#.
 I'm using OleDbConnection class, passing the follow connection string:

```
 @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=myfile.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;"""
```

It seems to work fine, but when I try to retrieve data from the loaded dataset I find that empty columns and empty rows have been automatically removed!

For example, suppose the XLS file have the first valued cell at position C4, if you try to get the value of the cell at row 3 and column 2 you will get an exception, while if you access to the cell at row 0 and column 0 you will find the value of cell C4.

So it seems that empty columns and rows are automatically *trimmed*, even if the HDR option (in connection string) is set to NO.

Thanks you.

Comment: have you tried using Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 ?

Comment: @Mithir Thanks... I've tried, but I get the exception message: "Could not find installable ISAM"

Comment: If the range you're querying starts at A1 and includes the blank cells, then the range is offset so your result starts at the first non-blank cell. But if you don't include the leading blank rows or columns in the range, then no cells are trimmed and there's no offset.  It's inconsistent.  Is there a way to tell if cells have been trimmed or not?